# How to pass extra variables to ansible as list of dictionary to ansible playbook by --extra-vars?

Tags: ansible

I want to pass variables to my ansible playbook by --extra-vars, and the type of variables is a list of dict like this:

```yaml
  list1:
    - { key1: "val1", key2: "val2" }
    - { key1: "val3", key2: "val4" }
```

My playbook is :

```yaml
---
- name: main file
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list1: "{{ lists }}"

  tasks:
  - name: echo item
    shell: echo {{ item.key1 }}
    with_items: list1
```

and I try to pass variables like this:

```
ansible-playbook build_and_cppcheck.yml -e "lists=[{ "key1": "val1", "key2":"val2" },{ "key1": "val3", "key2":"val4" }]"
```

But I get the following error which I don't know how to fix:

> fatal: [localhost] => with_items expects a list or a set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use JSON string syntax: [Ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line). For example:

`play.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "This is {{ test[0] }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "This is {{ test[1] }}"
```

which you call as like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml -e '{"test":["1.23.45", "12.12.12"]}'


PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is 1.23.45"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is 12.12.12"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************
localhost
```

Comment: question: I want to do this same but into a .sh file so:
- -e '{ "var1":[$VAR1], "var2":[$VAR2] }' having $VAR1=foo $VAR2=bar

But instead of obtaining foo & bar I am obtaining $VAR1 and $VAR2, so ansible is not resolving my input data in the sh.

Comment: @GeorgeFandango  -e '{ "var1":[$VAR1], "var2":[$VAR2] }' <= The single quotes prevent your shell from expanding $VAR1